# rubyでTimeオブジェクトが24時間以内かどうかを判定するには

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

rubyでDateTimeオブジェクトが24時間以内かどうかを判定するにはどうしたらよいのでしょうか。

`time = Time.zone.now`をして、しばらくしてから`time`を見に行って、24時間以内かどうかを判定したいのですが。

Comment: 現在時間のDateTimeオブジェクト - 起点のDateTimeオブジェクト <= 1

Comment: @BLUEPIXY 下にある回答欄に記載してください。

Comment: @yasu ちょっと明確でないなと思ってコメントにしました。 `Time.zone.now`って多分（Timeが拡張されたもの）Railsですよね。どちらにしてもTime クラスとDateTimeクラスでは別物ですので話がおかしいと思います。

Comment: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone

Answer (score 1):

```
time = Time.zone.now
time > 1.day.ago
```

Rails環境であれば、このように書くこともできます。
口語的にも読みやすくなるかと思います。

http://railsdoc.com/references/ago

Answer (score 0):

Railsの環境のようなので `1.day`を使うと簡単にかけます。

```
(Time.zone.now - time) < 1.day
```

で現在と指定した時間が1日(=24時間)以内であれば`true`になります。
もちろん`1.day`の代わりに`24.hours`でも構いません。